# python request get multi urls

Tags: python, get, http-request

i am trying to request multi urls using requests.get this is what i started with

```
for number in range(1,10):
    page =requests.get('http://google.com/page'+str(number),'http://yahoo.com/page'+str(number))
```

but what i get is an error 
TypeError: get() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)

i have also tried this

```
url=['','http://google.com/page','http://yahoo.com/page']

for number in range(1,10):
    page = requests.get(url[number]+str(number))
```

this gives me

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
urls = ['http://google.com/page','http://yahoo.com/page']

for url in urls:
    for number in range(1,10):
        page = requests.get(url+str(number))
```